# double quotes pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, double-quotes, txt

I have large txt file with multiple words and chars and I'm trying to read this file into a pandas dataframe, with each word or char in a different row.

The problem is that " is one of the chars, and the function reads all the words between two " as a single word (because of the quoting).

How can I address this char as another regular char and not as a quoting char? I tried to play with the parameters of the read_csv function but couldn't manage to fix it.

My code now: `data = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=None, delimiter = "\t")`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the parameter quotechar

```
data = pd.read_csv("a.txt", delim_whitespace=True, header=None,quotechar="~")
print(data.head())
```

**a.txt**

```
abc def xyz
"abc xyz" def
```

**Output**

```
      0     1    2
0   abc   def  xyz
1  "abc  xyz"  def
```

there are qoutes left this way.

Comment: Wait, this doesn't seem do anything. I am getting same output with and without the param. Sorry.

Comment: @abc123 It seems to happen due to `header=None`, putting it in gives me only two columns. instead of three

Comment: Yes :( and maybe I wasn't clear. I don't want to ignore the double quotes, I want them to be like a regular char.

Comment: @abc123 yeah I changed the quotechar to do it, I changed it to tilda, I doubt it will be in the text file. Check the answer now.

Comment: @abc123 can you please upvote this answer? I need one reputation to comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Try via numpy's `genfromtxt()` method:

```
import numpy as np

data=np.genfromtxt('data.csv',dtype='str',delimeter='\t',skip_header=1)

columns=np.genfromtxt('data.csv',dtype='str',delimiter='\t',skip_footer=len(data))
```

Finally:

```
df=pd.Dataframe(data=data,columns=columns)
```